# Making a function "Range" not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a function range that takes in start and end as parameters. I want it to give me a range of all numbers from the parameter start till end(inclusive).

```
function range(start, end) {
  array = []; 
  for(var i = start; start <= end; i++) {
    array.push(i);
  }
  return array;
}

console.log(range(1, 10));
// → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: You are incrementing `i`, but comparing `end` against `start`.

Comment: Change condition to `i <= end;` instead of `start <= end;` or better get rid of `i` and use `start`

Comment: if I am setting i to start, shouldn't they be interchangeable?

Comment: @wwang8421 A good read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language